# what is the transaction per second of hyperledger fabric with Kafka

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I want to know that how much transactions can be take place in one second over hyperledger fabric with Kafka protocol. I'm actually creating a network, as such project size is not as much big but if my product will do millions of transactions per second around the globe and want to log those transactions over hyperledger fabric so could it be possible that fabric can manage them all? If yes than how many nodes should i need to setup first and what should be the server specs to deploy the network. And if this is not the good idea of using fabric than kindly let me know which blockchain should i use to log the immutable and consortium ledger.